# How to write integration result symbolically

Tags: python, sympy

I'm new to using Sympy, though I can do definite integrals with something like `integrate(atan(x), (x, 0, pi/2))`. But how do I evaluate the integral non-numerically (symbolically)? Moreover, how do I evaluate *any* integral symbolically?

Sympy gives a numerical approximation even without `evalf()`. However, I want a symbolic approximation that uses pi, log, etc. I know that something like `nsimplify()` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use sympy's symbolic pi, then you will get a symbolic result. If you use a numerical pi value then you will get a numerical result.

```py
import sympy as smp

x = smp.symbols("x")
smp.integrate(smp.atan(x), (x, 0, smp.pi/2))
```

[image]

```py
import sympy as smp
import numpy as np

x = smp.symbols("x")
smp.integrate(smp.atan(x), (x, 0, np.pi/2))
```

[image]